# Beginner wanting to use optaplanner and graphhopper to solver Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: optaplanner, graphhopper

I'm new to VRP solving. I've got optaplanner's demo VRP running.

I have about 400 text addresses as my waypoints. I've geocoded them, so I have lat/long.

I sense that I need to calculate a LOT of distances between waypoints. I've seen the file format for .vrp and as yet haven't found how to generate that format from my list of text addresses.

I sense that graphhopper might help me to do that.

I'm still getting graphopper going. I have downloaded open street map data from https://extract.bbbike.org/ in PBF format. I sense that I need to use that to that data with graphhopper to generate input to optaplanner.

am I on the right track?

can someone point me to a guide? (I realise this is pretty niche, and I might have to find my way a little...)

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I should have said "i need to calculate a lot of ROAD DISTANCES". Air distance isn't so useful to me.

Comment: You can edit your post instead of commenting about your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the code](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator) how I generated the VRP file used in optaplanner-examples.

Comment: Thank you.
I got graphhopper running with my local map last night.

I see that some of the code you've made calls graphhopper for distances. (FromCsvLocationsToVrpGenerator.java). and see that I provide lat/long to grahhopper in a csv to define my waypoints.

I see that I can insert my local map in here somewhere (DataSource.java)
and other settings in the same directory.

Thank you for this. It seems exactly the direction I'm looking for. I hope my skills are up to getting it to run.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: As a side note, I think using the OSRM table API (http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#table-service) is a better solution to fetch a large matrix of drivetimes, as this API allows you to fetch all drivetimes between multiple locations in a single call. The open source version of Graphhopper unfortunately doesn't expose the matrix API, so you have to do a call for every location pair. Of course this will also work, but I think fetching it with a single call is nicer and probably faster. However, OSRM only returns drivetimes, not distances.